# How to get product variation media file url using jsonapi?

Tags: commerce, media, uri

I'm using the following jsonapi GET request to retrieve product variations for a product:

```
/jsonapi/commerce_product/default/0ea927c7-b62d-45c9-8bec-dc3d16215276/variations?include=field_images
```

However, the response does not include the file url for the media:

```
{
"type": "media--image",
"id": "6af50149-ae35-4a3b-802d-b21c5d863235",
"links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://myurl/en/jsonapi/media/image/6af50149-ae35-4a3b-802d-b21c5d863235?resourceVersion=id%3A4"
}
},
"attributes": {
"drupal_internal__mid": 4,
"drupal_internal__vid": 4,
"langcode": "en",
"revision_created": "2021-09-03T08:03:04+00:00",
"revision_log_message": null,
"status": true,
"name": "image-940375_1920.jpg",
"created": "2021-09-03T08:02:55+00:00",
"changed": "2021-09-03T08:02:55+00:00",
"default_langcode": true,
"revision_translation_affected": true,
"metatag": null
},
"relationships": {}
},
```

How do I add the media file url to the request?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
/variations?include=field_images.field_media_image&fields[file--file]=uri,url
```

Comment: If you need the links to image styles, check out the [Consumer Image Styles](https://www.drupal.org/project/consumer_image_styles) or [JSON:API Image Styles](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_image_styles) modules.

Comment: The JSON:API Image Styles module crashed my site and the Consumer Image Styles is a bit too complex for my use case.